# Convert Single Column Multiple Row Values to Multiple Column Single Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `L3` like below.

```
L3
---
4
6
```

Now I want to display these two Rows as Columns as follows:

```
L3  L4
--  --
4    6
```

Please ignore any aggregate functions involved to compare these data as they are not in any order and numeric values can change intermittently.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN L3=4 THEN L3 END AS L3, CASE WHEN L3=6 THEN L3 END AS L4 FROM <yourtable>;` I can't imagine this is what you want, but since you don't really explain how you get to that desired output...

Comment: why put one value in one column and the other in the second column?  What is the rule here -- there is no way to answer this unless you tell us how, is it every other row?

Comment: @JNevill , and Hogan - I get count of two columns of a table as a single column with two rows. Then, I want to split that rows of single output column to multiple column with single row so I can select that count and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you just want to alternate.  I would use the LAG() function to get the prior rows value and skip rows... something like this

```
SELECT L3, L4 
FROM (
  SELECT LAG(L3) AS L3, L3 AS L4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RN
  FROM A_TABLE_YOU_NAME
)
WHERE RN % 2 = 0
```

SQL Server will probably balk at not having an ordering for LAG() so you will have to give some ordering -- but if you don't care just use something.  Make sure you use the ordering for both LAG() and ROW_NUMBER() or you will get "interesting" results.

---

---

If you don't have LAG()

```
WITH numbered as (
  SELECT L3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RN
  FROM A_TABLE_YOU_NAME
)
SELECT B.L3 AS L3, A.L3 AS L4
FROM numbered A
JOIN numbered B ON A.RN = B.RN+1
WHERE A.RN % 2 = 0
```

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention that I use SQL Server 2008 R2. Lag() supports from version 2012.